# Job message shown in inbox, but I can't access it - Page not found

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

A few days ago I got a reply from an employer that I sent a job application to.

Now I can't access the message/application anymore. I can see it in my inbox at the top, but when clicking on it it says "Oh no! We can't find the page you're looking for."

This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages/2053831

Comment: You probably have more than one account, checking now.

Comment: Maybe https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372267/messages-not-loading is related

Comment: @Alex.K. Please don't bump ancient posts to the front page with non-essential edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had more than one account in the system. I've merged the two accounts together and you'll be able to view the message now.