# Messages not showing in inbox, page not found

Tags: support

The messages sent to me do not show up in SO inbox. The *page not found* appears when I try to follow the notification. The full message however does get forwarded to my email and small blurb appears in SO notifications. I take it is similar [to this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349390/job-message-shown-in-inbox-but-i-cant-access-it-page-not-found) as I had a previous account that I wanted deleted.

This started when I tried to modify the *Email Settings* on my SO account. Apparently I accidentally used the old email I requested to be deleted earlier. 
I would appreciate any support on this one.