# Got an inbox notification but I cannot access the message

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have the same problem as this [Job message shown in inbox, but I can't access it - Page not found](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349390/job-message-shown-in-inbox-but-i-cant-access-it-page-not-found). I thought I had merged it but I guess not. Any help would be appreciated.