# Can't open item in inbox - Page not found

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently changed my email to this account and I'm assuming that something has gone wrong during the merge of my accounts?

I can see the message that I've received in the drop down after clicking on the inbox icon to the top right but when I click on the message item I get "Page not found" page.

I found a post from a user experiencing a similar issue so it might be the same case for me.

[Job message shown in inbox, but I can't access it - Page not found](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349390/job-message-shown-in-inbox-but-i-cant-access-it-page-not-found)

Comment: As with the previous example that you linked, there appears to have been a desync between accounts when your core Q&A account had a merge. Can you confirm if you can read the inbox item now?

Comment: @GraceNote Hello, yes now my I can read my inbox items. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

We've fixed this issue by performing a merge on the Jobs end of the system. When accounts are merged on the public Q&A side of things, there's supposed to be merges that occur on the Jobs end as well. If it doesn't occur, then you end up in this state where you'll receive inbox items from a Jobs account that thinks it isn't actually linked to your Q&A account (it's linked to the merge stub instead) and thus doesn't think you have permission to view your message.

For future readers who may run into this issue (suddenly find 404 pages when checking inbox items for job offers) - please contact our support via the Contact Us footer at the bottom of every page.